# Install Graph Plugin for Elasticsearch 6.5.4

Tags: elasticsearch, graph, kibana

When I click Graph in Kibana, I get the following error:

Graph: Graph is unavailable for the current basic license. Please upgrade your license.

When i got to https://www.elastic.co/de/products/stack/graph i can see this text: 
The code for graph features is now open and available in our public GitHub repo.

Is it possible, to install and use this Graph plugin for elasticsearch with my basic license?

Comment: They opened the code, but to use the graph feature you still need a license. You can read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/products/x-pack/open)

Comment: Look at: https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions under `Kibana Explore and Visualize` `graph` is shown as a platinum feature.